# Prove $Z=1+X$ has a geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $(=)=\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}$ where i is a natural number

I need to prove $Z=1+X$ has a geometric distribution and find the $E(Z),V(Z),V(X),V(E)$

My attempt:

$X$ is a geometric distribution with $p=1/2$ so $E(X)=V(X)=2$

$Z=\frac{1}{2^{i+1}}+1=\frac{1+2^{i+1}}{2^{i+1}}$ and I got stuck here, how can I show this is geometric?

Comment: In your first line, you mean $P(X = i) = \frac 1{2^{i+1}}$?

Comment: yes sorry, you are right

Comment: Just use $P(Z = i) = P(X = i-1)$ and substitute. This tells you what $Z$ is, now you can figure out the expectation etc.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z=X+1$, then $$P(Z=i)=P(X+1=i)=P(X=i-1)=\frac1{2^{i+1-1}}=\frac1{2^i}$$

Hence we have shown that $Z$ is Geometric distribution with success probability $\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that if

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Bigg)^{x}\frac{1}{2}\cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{0;1;2;...\}}(x)$$

$$Z=X+1$$

Is the same Geometric distribution with parameter $0.5$ with the only difference that $X$ counts the failures before the first success while $Z$ counts the trials.

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[Z]=\frac{1}{p}=2$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p}-1=\frac{1-p}{p}=1$$

It is self evident that

$$\mathbb{V}[X]=\mathbb{V}[Z]$$

Comment: why noy $E(X)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @AspiringMathematician : $E(X)=2-1=1$